# opera returns offset auto how to get real offset number?

Tags: jquery, offset

This code

```
    var offset = $('#snapwrap_inner').offset();
    alert(offset.left)
```

in FF returns 0px but in Opera and Chrome is auto. How can I get real offset value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at least chrome is running the code before the entire window loads, which in that case you wouldn't be able to tell the offset relative to the document. try putting that var alert in an if statement and see if it works:

$(window).load(function() {

var offset = $('#snapwrap_inner').offset();
alert(offset.left);

});